# Is it safe remove a systemd service without stopping it first?

Tags: fedora, systemd, dnf, uninstall

Say, I want to completely get rid of a certain systemd service (e.g. NetworkManager):

```bash
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager
sudo dnf remove NetworkManager
```

Is the first line (with `stop`) necessary? Or can I just `remove` it right away without stopping it first?

Comment: In debian, the `prerm` scripts included in the package should stop the service for you.  Not sure about fedora though.

Answer (score 2):

You can but the `NetworkManager` may still run in RAM.

And the files occupied by that process might be not removable.

To `stop` it before `remove` would be reasonable.